# how to analyze model performance without any ML libraries using a BI tool?

Tags: prediction, performance, features

I have a dataset that has the ML model `predictions` along with the `true labels` column of the predictions and `all the features` used for the predictions and I want to make an analysis of `how the model used these features for prediction` **without using any ML libraries**.
essentially some plots, tables, stats anything related...
Also, I'm using a `BI tool` for this, and don't know if this is even possible because I have `limited functionalities`.
I'm looking for **ideas** or if someone has faced some kind of thing before please let me know how to approach this.
**Data**: tabular, features are integers, prediction scores are floats, true label is integer and the problem is Classification (binary)
Thank you for your time!